# cc static linking: How to import all symbols of just one .a library?

Tags: compiler-construction, hyperlink, linker, cc

I have 2 static libraries,

`libalgha.a`  with 2 functions: `func1()` and `func2()`

and

`libbeta.a` with 2 functions: `func3()` and `func4()`

I have 1 executable (`mytest`) linked with these 2 libs. The executable calls only `func1()` and `func3()`. So as I understand the linker will put only the symbol of these 2 functions into the executable.

The executable is loading with `dlopen()` in runtime a shared library (`libgamma.so`) and this shared library uses the function `func2()` from `libalgha.a`. When running `mytest` I get the error:

> symbol func2: referenced symbol not found

I can't include `libalgha.a` inside `libgamma.so` because of a Solaris 32/64 bits issue.

So how can I link `mytest` with all symbols of `libalgha.a` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a reference to `func2` in your program source like:

```
extern void func2 ();
void (*pfunc2)() = func2;
```

Alternatively, link the whole library into one object, using `ld -r`, and link that object to the executable, instead of the library. You may or may not need to extract objects, e.g., if the following does not work:

```
ld -r -o libbeta.o libbeta.a
```

then do

```
mkdir x
cd x
ar x ../libbeta.a
ld -r -o ../libbeta.o *.o
cd ..
rm -rf x
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `-u func2` would help. See the [manual page](http://www.opensolarisforum.org/man/man1/ld.html).

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a `--whole-archive` option as on GNU.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, the thing is, in the reality, there are hundreds of functions inside that static lib, that's why I was looking for a more general option like: "import-all-symbols-of-this-library". Indeed the --whole-archive option is not available in Solaris.